# Form Close Tag not working in php echo? Table Elements overrunning each other in compiling. Also what is wrong with my 'comment' input?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

[PHP] So, I'm working on a project in which I have to display elements from a table (an image, and 3 text elements) and then provide a 'comments' space below. However, when checking my code on the website, my output echos get misaligned, and upon inspecting element it appears that my `<td>`s are empty and that all the code has simply migrated to a new `<td>`. Additionally, my add comment form at the bottom, even with what I think is a properly formatted close tag, does not work and ends up grouping all below code in the following `<td>`s above it. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<font face="georgia" color="#4c4c4c">
<div
    id="wrapper";

    background-color:powderblue;color:black;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    padding:10px;">

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<h1> ... </h1>
<table style=cellpadding="1">
    <tbody>
            <?php
            echo"  <tr style=\"height: 24px;\"> <td style=\"width: 525px; height: 400px;\">";
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = ".";
            $password = ".";
            $dbname = ".";

            // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $sql = "SELECT title, price, rating, image, comments FROM uploads";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                // output data of each row
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo "
                    <img src= \"" . $row["image"] . "\" alt=\"Image Listing\" style=\"width:300px;height:300px;\"> 
                    <p>
                        <b>Title: </b>".$row["title"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Price: </b>".$row["price"].  "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Rating: </b>".$row["rating"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Comments: </b>
                        <br>".$row["comments"]."<br>";
                    echo "<form action=comments.php> 
                        <name=\"number\" id=\"number\" value=\"1\"> 
                        <br> 
                        <b>Input Comment: </b>
                        <input type=\"text\" id=\"comments\" name=\"comments\">
                        <br> 
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"> 
                        <br> 
                    </form> 
                    <br> 
                    <br>";
                }
            }

            echo "</td><td style=\"width: 525px; height: 400px;\">";

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 2)
            {
                // output data of each row
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo "
                    <img src= \"" . $row["image"] . "\" alt=\"Image Listing\" style=\"width:300px;height:300px;\"> 
                    <p>
                        <b>Title: </b>".$row["title"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Price: </b>".$row["price"].  "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Rating: </b>".$row["rating"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Comments: </b>
                        <br>".$row["comments"]."<br>";
                    echo "<form action=comments.php> 
                        <name=\"number\" id=\"number\" value=\"2\"> 
                        <br> 
                        <b>Input Comment: </b>
                        <input type=\"text\" id=\"comments\" name=\"comments\">
                        <br> 
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"> 
                        <br> 
                    </form> 
                    <br> 
                    <br>";
                }
            }
            echo "</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 24px;\"><td style=\"width: 525px; height: 400px;\">";

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 3) {
                // output data of each row
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "
                    <img src= \"" . $row["image"] . "\" alt=\"Image Listing\" style=\"width:300px;height:300px;\"> 
                    <p>
                        <b>Title: </b>".$row["title"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Price: </b>".$row["price"].  "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Rating: </b>".$row["rating"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Comments: </b>
                        <br>".$row["comments"]."<br>";
                    echo "<form action=comments.php> 
                        <name=\"number\" id=\"number\" value=\"3\"> 
                        <br> 
                        <b>Input Comment: </b>
                        <input type=\"text\" id=\"comments\" name=\"comments\">
                        <br> 
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"> 
                        <br> 
                    </form> 
                    <br> 
                    <br>";
                }
            }
            echo "</td><td style=\"width: 525px; height: 400px;\">";

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 4) {
                // output data of each row
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "
                    <img src= \"" . $row["image"] . "\" alt=\"Image Listing\" style=\"width:300px;height:300px;\"> 
                    <p>
                        <b>Title: </b>" . $row["title"] . "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Price: </b>" . $row["price"] . "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Rating: </b>" . $row["rating"] . "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Comments: </b>
                        <br>" . $row["comments"] . "<br>";
                    echo "<form action=comments.php> 
                        <name=\"number\" id=\"number\" value=\4\"> 
                        <br> 
                        <b>Input Comment: </b>
                        <input type=\"text\" id=\"comments\" name=\"comments\">
                        <br> 
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"> 
                        <br> 
                    </form> 
                    <br> 
                    <br>";
                }
            }
            echo "</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 24px;\"><td style=\"width: 525px; height: 400px;\">";

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 5) {
                // output data of each row
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "
                    <img src= \"" . $row["image"] . "\" alt=\"Image Listing\" style=\"width:300px;height:300px;\"> 
                    <p>
                        <b>Title: </b>".$row["title"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Price: </b>".$row["price"].  "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Rating: </b>".$row["rating"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Comments: </b>
                        <br>".$row["comments"]."<br>";
                    echo "<form action=comments.php> 
                        <name=\"number\" id=\"number\" value=\5\"> 
                        <br> 
                        <b>Input Comment: </b>
                        <input type=\"text\" id=\"comments\" name=\"comments\">
                        <br> 
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"> 
                        <br> 
                    </form> 
                    <br> 
                    <br>";
                }
            }

            echo "</td><td style=\"width: 525px; height: 400px;\">";

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 6) {
                // output data of each row
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "
                    <img src= \"" . $row["image"] . "\" alt=\"Image Listing\" style=\"width:300px;height:300px;\"> 
                    <p>
                        <b>Title: </b>".$row["title"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Price: </b>".$row["price"].  "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Rating: </b>".$row["rating"]. "
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Comments: </b>
                        <br>".$row["comments"]."<br>";
                    echo "<form action=comments.php> 
                        <name=\"number\" id=\"number\" value=\6\"> 
                        <br> 
                        <b>Input Comment: </b>
                        <input type=\"text\" id=\"comments\" name=\"comments\">
                        <br> 
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"> 
                        <br> 
                    </form> 
                    <br> 
                    <br>";
                }
            }


            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo"</td> </tr>"
            ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas for a solution to my formatting problem?
Another question I have is for the mounted form in slots 1,2,3,4,5 and 6. Why is it that whenever I try to input a comment it just gives me my prewritten error? The `comments.php` is as follows:

```
<?PHP
$dbhost = '.';
$dbuser = '.';
$dbpass = '.';
$db_name = '.';
$tbl_name = 'uploads';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db_name);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)or die("Cannot select DB");

$comments = (isset($_GET['comments']) ? $_GET['comments'] : null);
$number = (isset($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : null);
$sql = "UPDATE uploads SET comments=" . $comments . "Where id=" . $number;

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{ 
echo 'Upload Successful! Preexisting comments may have been replaced.';
echo '<a href="list.php">Click Here For Current Listings , with your comment           
added. </a>';
}
else{echo 'Comment Limit Exceeded! Comment not uploaded.';}
?>
```

Thank you for any answers, I've been struggling with this for weeks. I am pretty new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 5) {
                // output data of each row
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

?>

                    <img src=  <?php echo $row["image"]; ?> alt="Image Listing" style="width:300px;height:300px;"> 
                    <p>
                        <b>Title: </b><?php echo $row["title"];?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Price: </b><?php $row["price"];?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Rating: </b><?php echo $row["rating"]; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Comments: </b>
                        <br><?php echo $row["comments"];?><br>
                    <form action=comments.php> 
                        <name="number" id="number" value="5"> 
                        <br> 
                        <b>Input Comment: </b>
                        <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments">
                        <br> 
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                        <br> 
                    </form> 
                    <br> 
                    <br>
           <? }?>

           </td><td style=\"width: 525px; height: 400px;\">
```

i would do it a little different like this , you can style tables to make it look nice

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
<div style="width:500px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="500" >
<tr>
<td> row 1</td>
<td> row 2 </td>
<td> row 3 </td>
</tr>
<?php
$result="what ever you want to fetch";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<td><?php echo $row["row1"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["row2"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["row3"]; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</Html>
```

Comment: So, I'm confused about your upper code. It looks like you didn't use ' quotes or " quotes for the echo, and my question is, are you allowed to do that? I feel like that would give an error. However, thanks for the response?